# Writing something instead of 'None' when loop comes back empty

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I am parsing raw html with BeautifulSoup using a set of seven for loops that write to seven lists. I then write those lists to a Pandas data frame. In order to do that, all lists must be of equal length. But one of the seven lists always comes back shorter due to not finding data for some entries. I want it to put something in the list (like "missing"), even when it finds nothing, so that all lists end up having the same number of entries. Below is a simplified example with only two of the seven loops:

```
#FIRST LOOP
retweets = data.find_all(class_='Something')
for rt in retweets:
    rt2 = rt.get_text()
firstlist.append(rt2[0])

#SECOND LOOP
replies = data.find_all(class_='Something_else')
for rp in replies:
    rp2 = rp.get_text()
secondlist.append(rp2[0])
```

The first list generally comes back shorter, so I tried the code below, but the list length is still the same. It does not seem to put 'missing' when missing.

```
#FIRST LOOP
retweets = data.find_all(class_='Something')
for rt in retweets:
    rt2 = rt.get_text()
if rt2 is not None:
    firstlist.append(rt2)
else:
    firstlist.append('missing')
```

Comment: Well have you debugged why it's not appending missing, perhaps the length is shorter anyway rather than there is a missing/empty value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing your raw HTML, I think that the entries are completely missing in your file. In this case the list returned by `find_all` will only be as long as the number of entries present in the data. What you can do is check the length of each list and then pad the first list with the requisite number of `missing` values if it is shorter.

Another possibility is that the list does not contain "None" but an empty string and you will need to check for that.